# Как создать протокол для SerialPort с проверкой ошибок

Tags: c#, serial

У меня есть устройство выдающее мне сообщения вида [CommandID][Data][Data][CRC]. Если CRC не совпадает, то это значит, что где-то какой-то байт был попорчен, либо, что какой-то байт был потерян по пути и тут уже есть два варианта. После команды ничего нет и можно все проигнорить по таймауту, а если что-то еще пришло, то получается каша. Как это лучше все решить, наверняка уже есть готовые решения.

Comment: Добавьте поле длины пакета, а потом state machine и кольцевой буфер.

Comment: Добавить в отправляем код я ничего не могу, но длину команды я знаю по ее ID. Только мне это поможет, если мне придет вот такое [CommandID][Data][CRC][CommandID][Data][Data][CRC]. Первая команда ошибочная, вторая тоже хрень какая-то, тк не хватает байт

Comment: А, ну тогда все ОК: первый байт в очереди - ID, по нему вычисляете длину и ждете необходимое число байт. Как только они есть - проверяете CRC. Если совпало - выкидываете всю посылку из очереди. Не совпало - выкидываете один байт.

Comment: В том случае как у себя я делаю так. Вначале проверяю это [CommandID][Data][CRC][CommandID] и выкидываю. Потом проверяю [Data][CRC][CommandID][Data] и так пока я не дойдут до второй команды?

Comment: @Nodon Приведите код, который принимает пакеты. И код которым обрабатываете принятые пакеты. Скорее всего это поможет решить проблему.

Comment: @VadimPavlovich Я добавил в виде ответа, как я решил сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я свою задачку решил следующим образом.
Последовательно перебираю все входящие байты.
Если байт не соответствует ни одной из возможных комманд, то инкрементируем индекс.
Если соответует, то смотрим есть ли у меня достаточно сейчас байт для выполнения команды.
Если нет, то ждем прихода новых байтов.
Если да, то проверяем хеш сумму и там либо выполняем и увеличиваем индекс на длину команды, либо не выполняем инкрементируем индекс.

Позже кину пример кода, когда по тестирую его побольше.

Update 1: Код для обработки принятых байтов.

```
private bool TryParseCommand(byte commandID, out ReceiveCommand receiveCommand)
{
    foreach (ReceiveCommand command in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ReceiveCommand)))
        if (((ReceiveCommand)commandID & command) == command)
        {
            receiveCommand = command;
            return true;
        }
    receiveCommand = ReceiveCommand.State;
    return false;
}
private void DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    _rwlForSerialPort.EnterReadLock();
    if (!_port.IsOpen || _port.BytesToRead == 0)
        return;

    //Считываем байты в буфер
    int countOfReadedBytes = _port.BaseStream.Read(_bytesBuffer, _outIndex, _bytesBuffer.Length - _outIndex);
    _outIndex += countOfReadedBytes;

    while (_inIndex < _outIndex)
    {
        byte commandID = _bytesBuffer[_inIndex];
        //Проверяем поступившую команду
        ReceiveCommand receiveCommand;
        if (TryParseCommand(commandID, out receiveCommand))
        {
            //Проверяем есть достаточно ли у нас байт для проверки и выполнения команды
            if (_outIndex - _inIndex < _lenghtOfAnswer)
                break;
            //Проверяем хеш сумму
            byte crc8 = CalcCRC8(_bytesBuffer, _inIndex, _lenghtOfAnswer - 1);
            if (_bytesBuffer[_inIndex + _lenghtOfAnswer - 1] == crc8)
            {
                //Выполняем код соответвующий команде
                switch (receiveCommand)
                {
                    //Тут проверка и выполнение
                    default:
                        _inIndex++;
                        continue;
                }
                _inIndex += _lenghtOfAnswer;
                continue;
            }
        }
        _inIndex++;
    }

    if(_inIndex == _outIndex)
    {
        _inIndex = 0;
        _outIndex = 0;
    }
    else if (_outIndex == _bytesBuffer.Length)
    {
        //Мне проще перенести пару, чем каждый раз накладывать маску для расчета индекса в кольцовом буфере
        int bytesCount = _outIndex - _inIndex;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytesCount; i++)
            _bytesBuffer[i] = _bytesBuffer[_inIndex + i];

        _inIndex = 0;
        _outIndex = bytesCount;
    }

    _rwlForSerialPort.ExitReadLock();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

обратитесь к товарищу Token Ring за идеей - добавьте пару байт в начало пакета, преамбулу - со строгим значением, которое больше нигде не встречается.
Если попалось что-то непонятное, ждём следующую преамбулу.

Comment: Я добавил свой код, если хочешь можешь глянуть.

Comment: Что-то у меня Token Ring найти не выходит

Comment: в твоем коде фактически перед вызовом "if (TryParseCommand(commandID, out receiveCommand))" надо будет добавить что-то типа "if PreambleFound(_bytesBuffer)", да, лишние накладные расходы, но повышение надежности. Можно ведь за ид команды что-то другое принять. Как вариант - преамбула и финишный элемент, считывать буфер из порта до получения финишного, потом только парсить что есть

Comment: нет возможности код устройства поменять, не мы делали.

Comment: ок, судя по коду, поступает ровно 4 байта, можно во временные промежутки упереться для повышения точности - если за НН милисекунд пришло меньше 4байт = потерян

Comment: тоже дельное предложение.